# Visualizing the four subspaces of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a system of linear equations in the form $$AX=b$$ How can I go about visualizing the four fundamental sub-spaces - column space, row space, null space and left null space?

In the same context, how can I visualize the orthogonality of row space and null space, and column space and the left null space?

Comment: Before you imagine the subspaces, how do you imagine $n$ dimensions?

Comment: I don't know many people who can visualize more than 3 dimensions, but as far as this problem is concerned, I would be more than happy if I could just visualize the 4 subspaces in 3 dimensions1!

Comment: Einstein could do that, but... ;-)

Comment: Since "subspace of a matrix" is not really a standard expression, I have to ask this. Do "the four subspaces" refer to left/right nullspace, columnspace and rowspace?

Comment: Yep! I edited the question to be more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could type it all out, but I think this most efficiently gets you toward what you are after.

[image]

[Here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~lindblad/102/l7.pdf) is the original source.

---

[Here](http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Essays/newpaper_ver3.pdf) is another way to think about these things from Gilbert Strang:

[image]

Comment: Thanks JohnD! I am still trying to comprehend the first explanation. I am taking the course by Gilbert Strang and have come across the second picture. Hopefully, I will be able to get a clear picture from your answer!

Comment: What does the null space of C(A) look like? Is it inside the Columnspace of all Ax?

Comment: @Learningstatsbyexample V old q (& hopefully you found the answer) but, for the record, $\text{c}(A) = \left\{c_1\vec{a}_1+c_2\vec{a}_2+\cdots+c_n\vec{a}_n : c_i\in\mathbb{C}\right\}$, i.e., it yields a set (containing every possible combination of $A$'s column vectors), NOT a matrix! The 4 fundamental subspaces ($\text{c}(A)$, $\text{c}(A^T)$, $\text{n}(A)$, & $\text{n}(A^T)$) wrt a matrix $A$ yield sets.

Comment: Makes sense, @Landon. And yeah, my question was 4 yrs ago!